# Difference between django.core serializers and Django Rest Framework serializers

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, active-model-serializers

I am now learning Django and I just heard about Django Rest Framework (DRF). I was wondering what is the difference between the django.core serializers and the rest_framework serializers. Yes, I know DRF is for APIs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`django.core` serializers are meant for the purpose of serializing entire model instances into XML, JSON, or YAML, and vice versa. They don't do anything besides just serializing.

DRF's serializers are specifically for converting model instances into JSON objects *when dealing with data from HTML forms or API requests*. Thus, serialization is not always a smooth or straightforward process, as you may be passed illegitimate or incomplete data, or fields of the form may not correspond in an obvious way to the fields of the corresponding model(s). For this reason, DRF allows you to create custom subclasses of `serializers.Serializer` in order to clean and validate data that is passed to the server. This also allows you to customize the manner in which the data is stored in the model instance. [See the documentation here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).