# Django serializers vs rest_framework serializers

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

What is the difference between `Django serializers` vs `rest_framework serializers`?
I making a webapp, where I want the API to be part of the primary app created by the project. Not creating a separate App for the API functionality. Which serializer do I need to use for Django views and models, and at the same time will work for the API?

```
from django.core import serializers
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/

```
from rest_framework import serializers
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### tl;dr

**If you want to create just a *few* very small API endpoints and *don't* want to use DRF, [you're better off manually building the dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736881/how-to-build-a-json-rest-api-in-django-without-django-rest-framework/46759674). Django core serializers are not meant for external consumers.**

---

You can use the same primary app in your project and make it work with DRF in parallel. Just add a `serializers.py` file with the definitions, add the DRF logic in the same `views.py` file and do the routing. You could use [function based views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view).

## Detailed explanation of differences

Let's say you have the following model

```py
class Employee(models.Model):
  identification_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And you want to create an endpoint `/employees/` that returns all such objects with JSON representation

```
{
  "first_name": "Jon",
  "last_name": "Skeet"
}
```

---

### With Django serializers

```py
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse

class EmployeeView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        employees = Employee.objects.all()
        serialized = serializers.serialize(
          'json',
          employees,
          fields=('first_name', 'last_name'),
        )
        return HttpResponse(serialized)
```

and the result you get would be a list of dictionaries of the form

```
{
      "fields" : {
         "first_name" : "Jon",
         "last_name" : "Skeet"
      },
      "model" : "employees.Employee",
      "pk" : 12
}
```

But this isn't what we're looking for. Django core serializers are meant to [serialize models as representations of what's in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341102/difference-between-django-core-serializers-and-django-rest-framework-serializers). This is made explicit by the fact that [the `dumpdata` command uses it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata).

```sh
python manage.py dumpdata employees.Employee | json_pp
```

```
[
  {
      "fields" : {
         "identification_number" : "20201293",
         "first_name" : "Jon",
         "last_name" : "Skeet"
      },
      "model" : "employees.Employee",
      "pk" : 12
  }
]
```

Now, of course you could do some things to your code to get the representation you want, but **this module is not meant to be used for API views to be consumed by a external consumer**.

---

### With Django REST framework

Here we can create serializer classes that are independent of the Model. This is important since the external representation of the object is kept separate from the internal one.

```py
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = Employee
    fields = (
      'first_name',
      'last_name',
    )
```

and, trying to use only the most basic serialization-deserialization features of DRF, we would get

```py
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from django.http import HttpResponse

class EmployeeView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        employees = Employee.objects.all()
        serialized = EmployeeSerializer(employees, many=True)
        json_representation = JSONRenderer().render(serialized.data)
        return HttpResponse(json_representation)
```

and result in the representation we were looking for.

Now, of course you usually don't use DRF as in the last example, but instead

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets

class EmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
  queryset = Employee.objects.all()
  serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
```

It takes care of all the boilerplate so it's really convenient and, in contrast with the Django core serializers, this is really meant for external consumers.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts for a detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's a default vs advanced situation. The Django serialize has just one page of documentation, while Django Rest has a whole website for it. If your application uses a lot of APIs, then it makes sense to install a whole framework. But for smaller APIs you'd just use the default Django one. No need to use both at the same time. Also, use serializers in views.